# Android restarts activity although locales configuration changes are handled by app

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I followed the pathway to implement [Per-app language preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages)  in my app.
If the user opens the application for the first time, an activity to select one of the available languages is presented to the user.

Once the user has selected the language, `AppCompatDelegate` API is called, to
inform android about the language change.

```
// This code will be called some time after onCreate()
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
  val selectedLanguageIso = "en"
  val appLocale: LocaleListCompat = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(selectedLanguageIso)
  AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
}
```

Because I do not want android to recreate this activity, I added the flag
`android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"` in Manifest like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LanguageActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"/>
```

But for whatever reason, **android is ignoring the flag and still recreates my activity**, but only the first time `AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales` is called.
The user will see a weird flickering, before she or he is navigated to the next activity.

It will only be ignored the first time. If I manually change the language a second time,
then the flag is honoured.

I need to note, that I opted out of automatic locales storage.
So android will not have any language on the first app
start, until I do the handoff. Maybe this relates to the issue.

```
      <service
          android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:exported="false">
          <meta-data
              android:name="autoStoreLocales"
              android:value="false" />
      </service>
```

Does anybody experience the same?

**Edit. Add my current workaround usecase**

My current workaround:

I am using `InitializePerAppLanguageUseCase` in the `ViewModel` of my first activity.

ViewModel:

```kotlin
    init {
        initPerAppLanguage()
        //...
    }

    private fun initPerAppLanguage() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            initializePerAppLanguage() // <- Use Case, see below
        }
    }
```

UseCase:

```kotlin
/**
 * Checks if we need to initialize the app language in the android settings.
 *
 * This is unfortunately necessary, since android is ignoring our flag
 * in Manifest `android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"` for  the first Activity,
 * which causes an activity restart for the very first app open, when
 * `AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales` is called.
 *
 * For whatever reason, any following call to `AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales`
 * will honor the flag and no recreation is done.
 *
 * To fix this buggy behaviour, we manually call AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales
 * once with the default `Locale` which is used to start the application after install,
 * so the API is "initialized" and will not recreate our activity.
 *
 * @see AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales
 */
class InitializePerAppLanguageUseCase(
    private val defaultDeviceLanguage: String, // resolves to: Locale.getDefault().language
    private val appSettings: AppSettings
) {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    operator fun invoke() {
        
        if (!appSettings.isBoardingDone()) {
            // SupportedLanguages contains the languages my app can handle
            if (SupportedLanguages.languages.contains(defaultDeviceLanguage)) {
               setSelectedLanguage(defaultDeviceLanguage)
            } else {
                // Is a language we do not natively support, so we would anyway fallback to english
               setSelectedLanguage("en")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setSelectedLanguage(isoCode: String) {
        val localeListCompat = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(isoCode)
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(localeListCompat)
    }

}
```

Comment: Am facing the same issue. I know few apps are using this API on production and showing a animation on device > Android 12. Am still finding its as it janky and unpleasant UX.

Comment: Yes, facing same issue. Manifest should manage, but somehow it's not

Comment: Could you please try adding all the possible configuration and remove them one by one until this behaviour doesn't happen anymore?

Comment: Any help to avoid activity restart?

Comment: I can share my idea how to work around this issue. It does not fix it, but is good enough in terms that the activity is not restarted. I'll edit my question.